# plain text email from MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql, email, plaintext, line-breaks

The situation is the following. I stored a plain text email in MySQL containing linebreaks as `\r\n`. When my php script needs to send the mail it first fills in some parameters with `sprintf` and then the mail is sent with the standard `mail()` function.

The problem I encounter is that the email client (thunderbird in my case) displays these linebreaks instead of interpreting them.

To test my script I hardcoded a sentence in the mail. When I do this the mail is interpreted correctly. My first tought was that MySQL escapes the backslashes, so I tried to do a `str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $str)` but this doesn't help.

I'm obviously making a wrong assumption or stupid error, but I don't see it. What could be the problem?

Comment: why don't you print the result set of the query and see exactly what mysql returns?

Comment: I have done a print `$result['message']` and in the browser nothing is escaped.

Comment: Then, obviously the mail() function escapes your special chars

Comment: The `mail()` function doesn't escape the `\r\n` when I hardcode them. So I think this can not be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace it like this str_replace('\n\r', "\n\r"); It might solve your problem if the \n\r characters are saved in you message as four seperate characters. If you have inputted them using for example phpmyadmin they will be saves as 4 characters and not 2 characters as you expect.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you this solves the problem. I had indeed entered the test email in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: pay mind if you put escape characters between single quotes '' they will not be escaped. If you put them between double quotes they will be escaped! This is not true for the \' though. The \' will ofsource be escaped when it's placed between single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump to print the message, this might reveal better information on the value of the string.

Comment: I now tried a `var_dump` but it doesn't show escaped characters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use this to ty and remove the slashes:

```
stripslashes($str);
```

Comment: No the email client shows `rn` instead of `\r\n'. Really strange.